# Binary representation of bigint into a binary(8) column

Tags: mysql, binary

I'm trying to store the binary representation of a bigint unsigned number into a binary(8) column in MySql. For example, the value `9` should be stored as `0...01001`, complete with the obligatory left padding of a bunch of `0`s. Is this possible?

Comment: A `binary` column stores octets, not bits.  Do you mean the bigint unsigned value 9 should be stored as the octets `0x00` `0x00` `0x00` `0x00` `0x00` `0x00` `0x00` `0x09` -- also known as [big endian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) -- or are you thinking of something else?

Comment: Precisely - big endian is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `CONV(..., 10, 16)` to convert the number from base 10 to base 16.
- Take that result and left pad it with up to 16 0's: `LPAD(..., 16,'0')`
- Take that hex-encoded string and convert to binary with `UNHEX(...)`

So your expression is `UNHEX(LPAD(CONV(/* input value or column here */,10,16),16,'0'))`.

Examples using the `HEX()` function to turn the octets back into hex so that we can see the result:

```sql
mysql> SET @input = 9; SET @output = UNHEX(LPAD(CONV(@input,10,16),16,'0')); SELECT HEX(@output);

+------------------+
| HEX(@output)     |
+------------------+
| 0000000000000009 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @input = 65536; SET @output = UNHEX(LPAD(CONV(@input,10,16),16,'0')); SELECT HEX(@output);

+------------------+
| HEX(@output)     |
+------------------+
| 0000000000010000 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- largest possible bigint unsigned
mysql> SET @input = 18446744073709551615; SET @output = UNHEX(LPAD(CONV(@input,10,16),16,'0')); SELECT HEX(@output);

+------------------+
| HEX(@output)     |
+------------------+
| FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Warning: do not do any math involving literals inside the input expression, the first argument to `CONV()` -- e.g. do not try `CONV(18446744073709551610 + 4, ...` because MySQL will not do what you want.  Arithmetic operations on numeric literals are done with double precision floating point math, which leads to approximation errors on large and small numbers.  If your argument is a single number or a bigint unsigned column or variable, these work as expected.

Comment: Are there any performance implications (not including the conversion itself) between storing 8 byte values as unsigned ints vs 8 byte binary columns?

Comment: @BrianLeishman I'm not aware of anything meaningful.  Both `BIGINT UNSIGNED` and `BINARY(8)` are actually stored using 8 bytes.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Yup I knew that, I couldn't think of any reason why they should be different in terms of performance, but I just wanted to make sure, thanks though!